# My filter loop in scala doesn't work?

Tags: arrays, scala, loops, if-statement, for-loop

```
for(i <- data){
        if(i != 'a' || i != 'e' || i != 'i' || i != 'o' || i != 'u'){
            myArray(i) = i;
            println(myArray(i));
        }
    }
```

Data is a passed in string, and myArray variable is a char array. Why is it that when the char selected is in-putted into myArray it can be a vowel? Please help, thanks.

Comment: I told you, its a char array (var myArray = new Array[Char](200);)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your if condition like:

```
if(i != 'a' && i != 'e' && i != 'i' && i != 'o' && i != 'u')
```

You read it as if i is not a and not e and other then only its not a vowel. Also don't use i which will be value of your data as index of an array. Use a variable outside for loop something like:

```
var index = 0
```

and use this index variable and increment it.

Comment: yep. also, the index for myArray shouldn't be i

Answer (score 2):

I think more functional way to do the same is:

```
 def filterVowels(data: Array[Char]): Array[Char] = {
    data filter (isVowel);
  }
  val isVowel = Set('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
```